# Parallax using pseudo elements (and their height)

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax effect on my site, and have looked at several css solutions. I chose one by Joshua Bemenderfer that can be seen [here](https://alligator.io/css/pure-css-parallax/)

I've slightly edited the example code to make the problem more obvious, but because it's using a pseudo element, which matches its parent's size, when I resize the parallax section I'm struggling to stop white space around the image from being visible as it moves.

(NB you have to go full screen on the snippet to see the problem):

*EDIT: [Codepen because the snippet isn't showing the problem in full screen or in the preview](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/BaaXvoR)

```css
/* Tiny reset thingy */
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper {
  /* The height needs to be set to a fixed value for the effect to work.
   * 100vh is the full height of the viewport. */
  height: 100vh;
  /* The scaling of the images would add a horizontal scrollbar, so disable x overflow. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Enable scrolling on the page. */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Set the perspective to 2px. This is essentailly the simulated distance from the viewport to transformed objects.*/
  perspective: 2px;
}

.section {
  /* Needed for children to be absolutely positioned relative to the parent. */
  position: relative;
  /* The height of the container. Must be set, but it doesn't really matter what the value is. */
  height: 200px;
  
  /* For text formatting. */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.parallax::after {
  /* Display and position the pseudo-element */
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* Move the pseudo-element back away from the camera,
   * then scale it back up to fill the viewport.
   * Because the pseudo-element is further away, it appears to move more slowly, like in real life. */
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  /* Force the background image to fill the whole element. */
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Keep the image from overlapping sibling elements. */ 
  z-index: -1;
}

/* The styling for the static div. */
.static {
  background: red;
}

/* Sets the actual background images to adorable kitties. This part is crucial. */
.bg1::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
}

.bg2::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section class="section static">
    <h1>Boring</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section parallax bg2">
    <h1>SO FWUFFY AWWW</hi>
  </section>
    <section class="section static">
    <h1>Boring</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I can't seem to get it working without breaking the effect

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the pseudo element bigger to hide this bad effect. Simply make the top bottom value negative:

```css
/* Tiny reset thingy */
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.parallax::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -100px;
  left: 0;
  
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* The styling for the static div. */
.static {
  background: red;
}

/* Sets the actual background images to adorable kitties. This part is crucial. */
.bg1::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
}

.bg2::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section class="section static">
    <h1>Boring</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section parallax bg2">
    <h1>SO FWUFFY AWWW</h1>
  </section>
    <section class="section static">
    <h1>Boring</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I did think about this but thought that negative values might be poor cross browser. Does the approach look ok other than that? Thanks!

Comment: @NickW yes the approach is ok and there is no issue using negative value. They have the same support as positive ones and they are widely used ;)  you will notice how powerful they are if you start using them.

Comment: Thanks Temani - although I have noticed this can cause the pseudo element to expand past the last static section (if you don't mind taking a look at the codepen again you'll see it). Is it just a case of careful use of figures? It never ends! XD

Comment: @NickW can you give more details? I don't see any issue in your codepen ... also avoid to update the codepen you are using in the question or you will make your question irrelevant since no one can see the initial issue

Comment: If you add say -10rem to the top and bottom of the pseudo element to make it larger it then creates white space that extends past the static div below it. It should be visible in the code pen, but you're right, I'll change it back once you've seen what I mean, thanks

Comment: @NickW use a smaller value to make sure you don't get this issue

Comment: Yeah I figured that was probably the easiest way. Thanks